# In Vue 3 why do we have to use .value when setting a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In the [vue documentation - Writable Computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed), this example below is given.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const firstName = ref('John')
const lastName = ref('Doe')

const fullName = computed({
  // getter
  get() {
    return firstName.value + ' ' + lastName.value
  },
  // setter
  set(newValue) {
    // Note: we are using destructuring assignment syntax here.
    [firstName.value, lastName.value] = newValue.split(' ')
  }
})
</script>
```

and is used like this

```
fullName.value = 'John Doe'
```

The computed property is updated with .value otherwise it doesn't work. Is it because we use reactive (ref()) object in setter and getter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed) :

> **computed()**
> Takes a getter function and returns a readonly reactive **`ref`** object for the returned value from the getter. It can also take an object with get and set functions to create a writable `ref` object.

The can be well explained with Typescript definition :

```js
// read-only
function computed<T>(
  getter: () => T,
  // see "Computed Debugging" link below
  debuggerOptions?: DebuggerOptions
): Readonly<Ref<Readonly<T>>> //<---- return a readonly ref

// writable
function computed<T>(
  options: {
    get: () => T
    set: (value: T) => void
  },
  debuggerOptions?: DebuggerOptions
): Ref<T> //<-------- returns a ref
```